# Partition strategy

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

**Starting point**:
I fill one table with data and in order to compare the data from run to run, I added a column "run" (Integer).
I keep the last 5 runs. As I keep getting timeouts after 2 runs are in the table, I decided to partition the table on "run".

**What I did**:
1. I created the partitioned table with 1000 partitions (I suppose "run" to be from 1 to 1000), maximally only 5 partitions are there, the other 995 are empty and waiting until the moment when the next run gonna be put there.
2. I created partition scheme that uses the partition function described above and keeps all partitions (i.e. 1000) in PRIMARY file group.
3. I partitioned the table on "run".

**Result:** no timeout anymore, but the processing time increased by 50%.

**Question**:  which points were suboptimal in my partitioning strategy? Should I have created 5 partitions and changed the way I number the runs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Partitioning is not a solution for *performance* issues. You are looking for **indexes**. Partitioning will slow down processing and the best you can hope for is on-par performance with non-partitioned tables. Partitioning is a good fit for data management scenarios, for fast data move using partition switch (ETL or data expiration).

You need to investigate why are you getting time outs. An educated guess would indicate table scans (ie. missing indexes). A good methodology is [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx).

Comment: I got the timeout because for one of the steps in ETL process with more than 3 runs the table became too big to process. With partitioning it is processed only one partition, that's why I don't have timeout after partitioning (that's my thoughts at least). Building indexes, I still had timeout, probably I should try to build indexes after partitioning. I accept the decrease in performance, I'm just wondering if I can keep it low, changing the way I do the partitioning.

Comment: maybe. building indeces would be the next step. The question is if on the partitioning step it could be done the other way. i.e. imagine that having no index before and after partitioning, could it be done more optimally? For instance, is it ok to build 1000 partitions if only 5 are really needed? And thank for your competent answers and comments!

Comment: *1000 partitions, maximally only 5 partitions are there, the other 995 are empty and waiting*: definitely don't do this. Have 6 partition (5 use, one empty). Before load split the 6th into 2 so you have 7 and then load to get 6 in use and 1 empty. And so on. Having a large number of partitions is quite problematic prior to SQL Server 2012. With SQL Server 2012 (which extends support to 15k partitions) a lot of those issues were fixed and is OK to have 1k partitions. Still, the recommended pattern is to split before load and have necessary partitions + 1 (you always need +1 empty).

Comment: The +1 empty is required so that the split is fast. You want to split an empty partition (no data movement, metadata only), not one with data (slow, has to actually move rows around).